# Add dictionaries to nsdictionary as value for key

Tags: objective-c, nsdictionary

I have to prepare a dictionary for serialization and then post it to server. Dictionary may have several other dictionaries as values for @"items" key. But some brackets interrupt. And server response me an error html.

```
NSMutableArray *a = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    for(int i = 0; i < [self.cartCopy count]; i++) {
        NSString *itemNumber = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", i + 1];
        NSDictionary *tempDict = @{ itemNumber : @{
                                                     @"item_id" : [[self.cartCopy objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"id"],
                                                     @"quantity" : [[self.cartCopy objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"quantity"],
                                                     @"type" : [[self.cartCopy objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"type"],
                                                     @"color_id" : @"0",
                                                 }
                                    };
        [a addObject:tempDict];
    }

    NSDictionary *dict = @{
                           @"date":oDate,
                           @"address":oAddress,
                           @"name":oName,
                           @"shipping_date":oShippingDate,
                           @"receiver_phone":oReceiverPhone,
                           @"customer_phone":oCustomerPhone,
                           @"total_price": oTotalPrice ,
                           @"additional_info": @"asd",
                           @"items": a
                           };
```

UPDATE: My NSLog of string after [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dict options:kNilOptions error:nil] :

```
{"address":"asd",
"name":"asd",
"receiver_phone":"123",
"customer_phone":"123",
"total_price":"1",
"date":"2013-03-05 21:22:55",
"additional_info":"asd",
"items":[
    {"1":{
        "type":"2",
        "color_id":"0",
        "item_id":10,
        "quantity":"3"
        }
    },
    {"2":{
        "type":"1",
        "color_id":"0",
        "item_id":74,
        "quantity":"3"
        }
    }
    ],
"shipping_date":"2030-03-03 12:12:12"
}
```

I think the reason is square brackets. How can i delete them?

For example, it works perfectly with dictionary:

```
NSDictionary *dict = @{
                       @"date":oDate,
                       @"address":oAddress,
                       @"name":oName,
                       @"shipping_date":oShippingDate,
                       @"receiver_phone":oReceiverPhone,
                       @"customer_phone":oCustomerPhone,
                       @"total_price": oTotalPrice ,
                       @"additional_info": @"asd",
                       @"items": @{
                               @"1":@{
                                    @"type":@"1",
                                    @"color_id":@"0",
                                    @"item_id":@"1",
                                    @"quantity":@"1"
                                    },
                               @"2":@{
                                    @"type":@"1",
                                    @"color_id":@"0",
                                    @"item_id":@"1",
                                    @"quantity":@"1"
                                    }
                               }
                    };
```

Comment: What problem are you running into?

Comment: How can i delete interfering brackets. I updated question

Comment: The square brackets denote an array. You need to speak to the server devs to find out what format they require for the JSON. The format will be a list of names (keys) and data types (values) for the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example that works perfectly the items object is a dictionary with keys {1, 2}.

In your output JSON your items object is an array.

This array contains 2 objects, each one is a dictionary.

The first contains a single key {1}.
The second contains a single key {2}.

You just need to remove the array and use a dictionary instead to store these dictionaries.

Answer (score 0):

That looks as if you want to send [JSON](http://www.json.org) to the server. You can create JSON data from your dictionary with

```
NSError *error;
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dict options:0 error:&error];
```

If you need it as a string:

```
NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Comment: Yes, i do so after. But before i need to prepare my dictionary "dict", because my format is wrong.

Comment: @Asike: A dictionary is a collection of key/value pairs. You cannot "prepare" a dictionary format. The brackets that you see is only how the debugger or NSLog() *displays* the dictionary. - Please try to convert the dictionary to JSON with this code. If it does not work, update your question.

Comment: @Asike: Your dictionary contains an array. Arrays are enclosed in square brackets in JSON. - Please tell us how exactly the output should look like.

Comment: I use an array only because I need combine several dictionaries. Is there any other way, to collect dictionaries without an array?